# Applescript click on save button

Tags: applescript

I got error; Can’t get button "save" of process "TextEdit".

```
 activate application "TextEdit"
 tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
 keystroke "s" using {command down}
 click button "save"
 end tell
```

I was also tring to include like "of window 1" still I can't get this working. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just talk to the app directly ?

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    tell document 1 to save
end tell
```

if you must use the GUI you need the correct hierarchy ( but it is best to talk to the app directly)

```
activate application "TextEdit"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TextEdit"
        keystroke "s" using {command down}
        delay 1
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: If I want to click on menu item Rename or export to pdf then I need to click on "save" button

Comment: you can save as, look at the dictionary

Comment: thanks a lot, where can I learn about "how to use applescript dictionary/library?

Comment: in script editor use file menu "open dictionary" then choose the application you want to work with

Comment: and i guess you can't export, you might want to use a different app that has better applescript support lol

Comment: I knew to open the dictionary of supported app but I don't know how to implement or use it with applescript. I'm a newbie to applescript and I did learn considerable amount of applescript still not sure how to use dictionary.

Comment: All I want to do is export a safari page into pdf using the menu item export to pdf. I did look several places they all use long GUI which goes via print, save as pdf, ..... it's too much. Easier would be export as pdf from file menu.

Comment: good resource, thanks. can I have ur id in macscripter, it'll be very helpful to learn not only applescript but also web developments. Mine is chittu

Comment: its the same :) actually